# German visa refusal on lack of proof of ties to home country. Should we appeal for review?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, german-residents

I am currently living in Germany on Blue Card and receiving a handsome salary. My wife is living in Pakistan. We are a newly married couple. She has registered herself in German Consulate for the family reunion visa but the waiting time to get the appointment is more than a year.

So, we decided to apply for a short-term Schengen visa (alongside waiting for the family reunion appointment date). She applied with all the required documents but got a refusal. The reasons for refusal are "You could not prove sufficient family ties to home country" and "You could not prove sufficient economic ties to home country".

I understand the reasons as stated someone else that She should provide followings:

1. A steady job with income.
2. Family ties (kids going to school for example, spouse, etc.).
3. Property or other assets.
4. Other similar evidence.

But the problem is,

1. She does not have any job (no employment relationship).
2. She is living with my parents and she does not own any house or property (no family ties and no economic bond).
3. She has finished her last degree and she is not enrolled in any school or university.
4. She does not have any kids.
5. She never visited Europe before (no last Schengen-Visa).

In the consideration of the above points, what can she have as a proof to show family and economic ties? What can we write in the appeal to convince that she doesn't have any intension to stay in Germany for more than 90 days as we have already registered for the family reunion visa in the consulate before applying to Schengen Visa?

I believe that from my side and other documents are Okay (we provided all the documents that we can), we just need to provide any document that shows her ties to home country Pakistan. Please guide what documents can we provide. Is it a deadlock for her?

Comment: By your own admission she doesn’t have any ties to Pakistan and she has a pretty strong one to Germany given that she’s already told them she wants to emigrate to Germany to join her husband.

Comment: So, that means, review an appeal or reapply is useless? We shouldn't do that? Or still, there is a way?

Comment: **Every** factor in her visitor visa application shows strong ties to Germany and only a single weak tie (living with your parents) to Pakistan. Because the officer assessing the tourist visa application has to decide if the applicant will leave Germany at the end of the proposed visit, these facts are a definition of a very weak application. This is especially so when combined with her previous application to emigrate, a clear statement that she does not wish to leave Germany. Do you see an error in the denial of this visitor visa? What is it?

Comment: @maxpayne IMHO an appeal is useless.

Comment: Perhaps she applied for the **wrong kind** of visa. Ask at Expatriates Stack Exchange if she qualifies for a family reunification with out.

Comment: @o.m. The last sentence of the first paragraph of the question suggests that a family reunification visa is already in process, but is thought to take too long.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica What I am thinking is, why would anybody want to be an illegal immigrant or by asylum when he/she can be legally migrant by family reunion visa. In my wife's case, she has already declared to the consulate by registering herself for the family reunion visa that she doesn't want to stay in Germany on Schengen visa, she would come back and process the family reunion visa. Doesn't it make sense?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The only reason she wants to visit now is strangely more than one year's delay time in appointment and the whole process would might take 2 years.
Secondly, I am sponsoring her, and I have good traveling history, never got any visa rejection. In visas cases, sponsor history doesn't matter?

Comment: @Traveller So that means, we must wait for two years for a family reunion visa to be processed. No other option or you think there is any other way?

Comment: From Germany's POV, her very weak ties to Pakistan mean she's a very high risk to not leave Germany at the end of a visit. That you (and she) feel differently about this than the German visa authorities feel is irrelevant to the German visa authorities. Seems to me that appealing or filing for a new tourist visa will not succeed, and it's even possible that such action(s) will spill over and impair the ultimate chances of success with the family reunion visa. I think you're better off to wait it out. In the interim, you can from time to time meet her in a third country.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I understand. Thank you for your time and valuable advice.

Comment: You're welcome. I wish both of you success in this venture.